# Доопределение данных в DataFrame по косвенным признакам

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

Задача состоит в определении количества для колонки 'quant' по косвенным признакам из других колонок.
Есть DataFrame:

```
    df = pd.DataFrame({'group': ['gr1', 'gr2', 'gr2', 'gr3', 'gr3', 'gr3', 'gr4', 'gr4', 'gr4', 'gr4'],
                       'block': [0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2],
                       'bl1': [1, 2, 2, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 2, 2, np.nan, np.nan],
                       'bl2': [np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 3, 3, 3, np.nan, np.nan, 2, 2], 
                       'title': ['A1_1', 'B2_1', 'B2_2', 'C3_1', 'C3_2', 'C3_3', 'D4_1', 'D4_2', 'D4_3', 'D4_4'],
                       'quant': np.nan})

    df
        group   block   bl1     bl2     title   quant
    0   gr1     0   1.0     NaN     A1_1    NaN
    1   gr2     1   2.0     NaN     B2_1    NaN
    2   gr2     1   2.0     NaN     B2_2    NaN
    3   gr3     2   NaN     3.0     C3_1    NaN
    4   gr3     2   NaN     3.0     C3_2    NaN
    5   gr3     2   NaN     3.0     C3_3    NaN
    6   gr4     1   2.0     NaN     D4_1    NaN
    7   gr4     1   2.0     NaN     D4_2    NaN
    8   gr4     2   NaN     2.0     D4_3    NaN
    9   gr4     2   NaN     2.0     D4_4    NaN
```

Надо выполнить расчет для колонки "quant" по следующему алгоритму:
1) По группам (в колонке 'group') в разрезе данных колонки 'block', необходимо определить количество записей.
Например, для

```
gr1 блок 0 = 1; 
gr2 блок 1 = 2;
gr3 блок 2 = 3;
gr4 блок 1 = 2;
gr4 блок 2 = 2.
```

2) Полученный результат надо сравнить с данными в колонках 'bl1' или 'bl2' по условию: если в колонке 'block' установлено значение "0" или "1",  данные для сравнения берем из 'bl1', если "2" – из 'bl2'. Сравнение можно выполнить по любой записи из соответствующей группы.

```
                     bl1     bl2    quant
group block title           
gr1     0   A1_1    1.0     0.0     0.0
gr2     1   B2_1    2.0     0.0     0.0
            B2_2    2.0     0.0     0.0
gr3     2   C3_1    0.0     3.0     0.0
            C3_2    0.0     3.0     0.0
            C3_3    0.0     3.0     0.0
gr4     1   D4_1    2.0     0.0     0.0
            D4_2    2.0     0.0     0.0
        2   D4_3    0.0     2.0     0.0
            D4_4    0.0     2.0     0.0
```

Если они равны, в колонку «quant», для каждой записи из группы, пишем соответствующий результат: result = x / y. (Понимаю, что во всех случаях он будет равен «1»).
Результат:

```
                     bl1     bl2    quant
group block title           
gr1     0   A1_1    1.0     0.0     1.0
gr2     1   B2_1    2.0     0.0     1.0
            B2_2    2.0     0.0     1.0
gr3     2   C3_1    0.0     3.0     1.0
            C3_2    0.0     3.0     1.0
            C3_3    0.0     3.0     1.0
gr4     1   D4_1    2.0     0.0     1.0
            D4_2    2.0     0.0     1.0
        2   D4_3    0.0     2.0     1.0
            D4_4    0.0     2.0     1.0
```

Comment: Можете привести пример где в результате будут не только единицы? И еще что значит `result = x / y`?

Comment: В данном случае рассматриваю только штучные единицы измерения (типа: шт, комплекты и пр.). В колонках  bl1 и  bl2 хранятся суммовые показатели по группам. Отсюда result = x / y, где x - количество записей в группе, y - общее количество в группе.
Следующим этапом пойдут литры, кг, м2, и т.д.

Хочу понять, как обрабатываются данные для bl2, если в коде `tmp = df.groupby(["group", "block"])["bl1"].transform("size")` только "bl1"?

Comment: При использовании функции `"size"` можно указать любой столбец, например: `tmp = df.groupby(["group", "block"])["block"].transform("size")
`

Comment: чем отличаются `количество записей в группе` от `общее количество в группе`?

Comment: Общее количество, в данном случае, дается в штучных единицах измерения, например, если количество записей - 2, и 2 шт. приходится на группу, значит на каждую запись приходиться по 1 шт., т.е. `result = x / y`

Comment: Не совсем понимаю, как работает `df.loc[:, "quant"] = np.where(df["block"].isin([0,1]), 
                                       df["bl1"] == tmp, 
                                       df["bl2"] == tmp).astype("int8")`.
Если можно, опишите пожалуйста подробнее.

Comment: дополнил ответ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
In [11]: tmp = df.groupby(["group", "block"])["block"].transform("size")

In [12]: tmp
Out[12]:
0    1
1    2
2    2
3    3
4    3
5    3
6    2
7    2
8    2
9    2
Name: bl1, dtype: int64

In [13]: df.loc[:, "quant"] = np.where(df["block"].isin([0,1]), 
                                       df["bl1"] == tmp, 
                                       df["bl2"] == tmp).astype("int8")

In [14]: df
Out[14]:
  group  block  bl1  bl2 title  quant
0   gr1      0  1.0  NaN  A1_1      1
1   gr2      1  2.0  NaN  B2_1      1
2   gr2      1  2.0  NaN  B2_2      1
3   gr3      2  NaN  3.0  C3_1      1
4   gr3      2  NaN  3.0  C3_2      1
5   gr3      2  NaN  3.0  C3_3      1
6   gr4      1  2.0  NaN  D4_1      1
7   gr4      1  2.0  NaN  D4_2      1
8   gr4      2  NaN  2.0  D4_3      1
9   gr4      2  NaN  2.0  D4_4      1
```

---

функция [np.where(condition, x, y)](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) работает следующим образом:

- если условие `condition` выполняется для текущей строки, то `np.where()` возвращает `x` (это может быть скаляр - значит для всех строк, которые удовлетворяют условию берется одинаковое значение `x` или список/массив/ndarray/Pandas.Series/в общем нечто списко-подобное. В этом случае берется соответствующий элемент из `x`)
- если условие `condition` не выполняется для текущей строки, то `np.where()` возвращает `y` (для `y` действуют те же правила что и для `x`)

Comment: Спасибо!!! @MaxU

Comment: Я правильно понимаю по `np.where(`), что  `df["block"].isin([0,1])` - это условие, при удовлетворении которого возвращается `df["bl1"] == tmp`. Если условие не выполняется, возвращается `df["bl2"] == tmp`....
Не могу понять, как появляются "1" в колонке "quant", так как возвращаются результаты сравнения, при чем не всегда равные "1".

Comment: @БорисЖуравлев, `1` - это `True` преобразованное к `np.int8`. Я так и не понял как вы хотите считать `result = x / y`

Comment: Спасибо!!! @MaxU, теперь все встало на свои места... Не знал о такой возможности!
По вашему вопросу: представьте, что нам нужно проконтролировать количество картошки в мешке в штуках. При этом, мы знаем, сколько всего картошки в мешке, например x = 50 шт. (наши колонки "bl1" и "bl2" обладают такой информацией). Для решения такой задачи мы должны перебрать каждую картофелину (наши записи) и сумму (y) сравнить с данными по мешку (допустим, что x = y = 50) ((наши колонки "bl1" и "bl2").  Если равенство сохраняется, то result = x / y. Это частный случай и результат всегда будет равен 1. Продолжу

Comment: а теперь проделаем то же самое, но с литрами. В группе 7 записей, общее количество 70 литров...
Подход с расчетом result = x / y универсальный, он подходит и для штук и для литров, просто логика будет другой. А результат рассчитываться будет одинаково. Выполняем 70/7 и получаем кол-во для каждой записи = 10 литрам.

Comment: @БорисЖуравлев, гораздо лучше привести маленький пример данных с литрами и кг. и такой чтобы не во всех строках получалась `1` - тогда будет намного понятнее, IMO

Comment: @MaxUОбязательно покажу, пока решаю вопрос с логикой - когда такой подход можно будет применить...

Comment: А преобразование True  к 1 - это  фишка!!! Не подскажете, где про такие вещи можно почитать?

Comment: @БорисЖуравлев, где почитать не подскажу... В данном случае это аналог `int(True)` в Vanilla Python ;)